# migrating from boto2 to 3

Tags: python-3.x, boto, boto3

I have this code that use boto2 that I need to port to boto3, and frankly I got a little lost in the boto3 docs:

```
connection = boto.connect_s3(host=hostname,
                             aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                             aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                             is_secure=False,
                             calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat())
s3_bucket = connection.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

I also need to make this work with other object stores that aren't aws S3.

Comment: This WILL NOT works with other object stores, because it is boto specific, and boto3 does NOT support other object store. You must write a wrapper for your application, to make acquire object without directly interact with the background API .

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                  aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                  endpoint_url=hostname, use_ssl=False)
response = s3.get_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

[client docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client)

[s3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client)

Comment: how about the `calling_format` parameter ? Is that no longer used ?

Answer (score 0):

boto3 and boto are incompatible. Most of the naming are NOT backward compatible.

You MUST read the boto3 documentation to recreate script. The good news is, Boto3 documentation is better than boto, though not superb (many tricky parameter example not provided) .

If you have some apps using some old function, you should create a wrapper code for it to make the switching transparent.

Thus, you instance any object store connection through wrapper, then instantiate various bucket usign different connector. Here is some idea.

```
#AWS 
# object_wrapper is a your bucket wrapper that All the application willc all 
from object_wrapper import object_bucket
from boto3lib.s3  import s3_connector
connector = s3_connector()
bucket = object_bucket(BucketName="xyz",  Connector=connector)


# say you use boto2 to connect to Google object store
from object_wrapper import object_bucket
from boto2lib.s3 import s3_connector 
connector = s3_connector()
bucket = object_bucket(BucketName="xyz",  Connector=connector)

# say for Azure
from object_wrapper import object_bucket
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
connector = BlockBlobService(......)
bucket = object_bucket(BucketName="xyz",  Connector=connector)
```